# Como inserir dados do inpuText em uma lista, utilizando JSF?

Tags: java, java-ee, jsf-2.2

Tenho o seguinte problema:

Preciso de um formulário para submeter questões de prova. Sendo assim, o formulário deve conter um campo para a pergunta(enunciado da questão), e vários campos para as alternativas.

Com isso, queria que os valores dos input's das alternativas fossem direto pra uma lista de alternativas instanciado no respectivo bean.

Assim temos a classe Opção:

```
public class Opcao {

    private int idOpcao;
    private String nomeOpcao;

    public int getIdOpcao() {
        return idOpcao;
    }
    public void setIdOpcao(int idOpcao) {
        this.idOpcao = idOpcao;
    }
    public String getNomeOpcao() {
        return nomeOpcao;
    }
    public void setNomeOpcao(String nomeOpcao) {
        this.nomeOpcao = nomeOpcao;
    }

}
```

E o o bean contendo a lista de opções:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class QuestaoBean {

    private List<Opcao> opcoes;

    public List<Opcao> getOpcoes() {
        return opcoes;
    }
    public void setOpcoes(List<Opcao> opcoes) {
        this.opcoes = opcoes;
    }
}
```

Comment: E como está seu .`xhtml`?

Comment: @Luídne eu não faço ideia de como criar o `<h:inputText>` referenciando essa lista. Nem precisa ter o `.xhtml.`, só preciso saber como irá ficar o `<h:inputText>`.

Answer (score 1):

O método `adicionarOpcao()` adiciona uma nova opção à lista com o dado vindo do `<h:inputText>`.
Após enviar os dados do formulário (`execute="@form"`) e a execução do método acima o `<f:ajax>`, que foi acionado pelo `<h:commandButton>`, atualiza o formulário (`render="@form"`) com os dados da lista atualizados.

**Controller**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class QuestaoBean {

    private List<Opcao> opcoes;
    private Opcao opcaoParaAdicionar;

    public QuestaoBean() {
         this.opcaoParaAdicionar = new Opcao();
    }

    public void adicionarOpcao() {
        if(opcoes == null) {
           opcoes = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        opcoes.add(opcao);
        opcao = new Opcao();
    }

    // getters e setters
}
```

**View**

```
<h:form>
    <ui:repeat value="#{questaoBean.opcoes}" var="opcao">
        <h:outputText value="#{opcao.nomeOpcao}" />
        </br>
    </ui:repeat>

    <h:inputText value="#{questaoBean.opcaoParaAdicionar.nomeOpcao}" />
    <h:commandButton value="Adicionar" action="#{questaoBean.adicionarOpcao}">
        <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Segue abaixo um exemplo simples:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{opcao.idOpcao}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{questaoBean.opcoes}" 
                   var="opcao" 
                   itemValue="#{opcao.id}"
                   itemLabel="#{opcao.nameOpcao}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="bean.acao" />
```

Dessa forma o objeto 'opcao' instanciará apenas o 'idOpcao', portanto no método 'bean.acao' há necessidade de código para consultar a descrição da opção com respectivo id.

A maneira correta seria criar uma classe OpcaoConverter que implementa a interface Converter, permitindo a instanciação completa de 'opcao' e não apena o atributo 'idOpcao'.